# Cannot read non http only cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am setting a cookie in a java/kotlin application like so. Notice i set httpOnly to false:

```kotlin
    @PostMapping("/authenticate/token")
    open fun authenticateAccessToken(
        @RequestBody jsonOneTimeToken: JsonOneTimeToken,
        exchange: ServerWebExchange,
    ): Mono<JsonToken> =
       identityClient.authenticateAccessToken(jsonOneTimeToken, exchange).doOnNext {
            exchange.response.addCookie(ResponseCookie.from("tmtools_token", it.token).httpOnly(false).build())
        }
```

I can then actually see my token:

[image]

But for some reason I can't read it:

[image]

Everywhere I look, the solution is the make sure that httpOnly is set false, but it is already the case.

The only thing else I can add is that we are using a AWS CloudFront, but it feels like, if it was an issue, it would set the httpOnly to true, but it clearly doesn't. Also, [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) can<t read the cookie either.

Comment: Does it match the path?

Comment: Looks like it’s scoped to the api path

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I'll try to add .path(null) to my kotlin code

Comment: That may not be what you want. It would be included on everything then

Comment: Actually, I want to index to be able to read the token, so it seems to be in order for me. That being said, .path(null) did not work, I will try .path("/") instead.

Comment: Alright, that worked for me. Thanks a lot! If you have further suggestion, you may make an official answer to this question and I will integrate your advice in my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Daniel A. White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23528/daniel-a-white) pointed out in the comments, the problem was that the path of the cookie did not match the path the ui was on. Since I want the index to be able to read the cookie, i added this code .path("/") to the cookie creation code.

Thanks again